# Windows 7 Phone - Putting a delay in screen navigation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, navigation, delay, sleep

Hi
I am trying to delay the screen navigation. After loading MainPage screen, I want to navigate to MainMenu screen after 3 seconds. I have written the following code for that.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Default_Loaded);         
    }

    private void Default_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Thread.Sleep(3000);
       this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MyProject;component/MainMenu.xaml", System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

But this code does not seem to work. The expected delay (3 seconds) is not there. Can anyone please help?

Best Regards

Comment: Just out of interest, what is your reason for having the delay?

Comment: Actually after displaying the splash screen, I take user to a screen on which i display icons of featured products to introduce user to them. I display that screen for 3 seconds and then redirect user to the main menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things you can try (and a last minute thought).

**1st**, I've seen people complain the Thread.Sleep() isn't working, but in each case they've been doing it on the UI thread. I've used Thread.Sleep() successfully myself, but when doing so it's been in a background worker thread. I haven't investigated this further as yet, but you may like to check it out.

A good walkthrough on using background worker here (posted by Pham Tien Sinh on msdn).

[Phạm Tiểu Giao - Threads in WP7](https://blogs.opera.com/news/)

**2nd**, you coud alternatively implement a timer. Two options for that here.

[DispatcherTimer Class (System.Windows.Threading)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(VS.95).aspx)

[Timer Class (System.Threading)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(VS.95).aspx)

Oh, **one other thing that comes to mind**, since you're doing some startup navigation trickery... checkout Peter Torr's posts on the topic of places and redirecting navigation. You might find some useful gems there depending what you're trying to do. Good content to be aware of in any case.

[Introducing the concept of “Places” - Peter Torr's Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20140502114508/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/introducing-the-concept-of-places.aspx)

[Redirecting an initial navigation - Peter Torr's Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ptorr/redirecting-an-initial-navigation?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: That was great! I used Timer class and it worked perfectly. Thanks Mick.

Answer (score 1):

I just used it and it worked fine. Just in case I added

```
using System.Threading;
```

and

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna **freeze** application (for example you need to test threads) and for some reasons you don't wanna use Thread.Sleep() you can make your own, simply Sleep function

```
public static class Threads
{
    public static void Sleep(int milisec)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime endOfSleep = now.AddMilliseconds(milisec);

        while (DateTime.Now < endOfSleep)
        {
        }
    }
}
```